# Letting the system calculate how much to add to counter based on dates in php

Tags: php

This is a cronjob script. The cronjob is running every minute.

The cronjob is to update a live-counter field in the database.

I'm having two times and a count limiter:

```
start: 2012-08-29 09:55:00
end: 2012-08-29 19:00:00
limit: 5000
```

How can I out from the start date, end date and limit given make the system calculate a number to add to the counter this execution?

So when the end date is over, the counter should be as big as the limit entered

Example, right now I got this:

```
if ( $setting['limit'] > $setting['counter'] )
{
        $rand = rand(5, 300);

        DB::update('settings')
        ->set(array('counter' => DB::expr('counter+ '.$rand)))
        ->where('id', '=', $setting['id'])
            ->execute();
}
```

This simply just gives me a number between 5 and 300 and adds to the counter each refresh/execution of the script.

With this there's a big possibility that the counter does not reach the limit, e.g if the start date and the end date is close to eachother and the random values is below 100 theres no way it will reach the limit 5000.

So how can you make the system calculate a correct ratio number to add to the counter, based on the start and end dates, the limit and the current count?

Comment: You mean you want at the end to have the `counter` to be `5000`?

Comment: Does the counter start at 0 at the start time every time?

Comment: @AlexLunix No it stores to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Counter Limit * (Current time in minutes - Start time in minutes)/(End time in minutes - Start time in minutes) = Current counter number
```

Basic ratios, although this is more a math question than a programming question...

Also, you may need to round the result, if you're not using a MySQL type that supports decimals.

So in your cronjob:

```
$start=strtotime($setting["starttime"]);//Or whatever your local copy of the start time is
$end=strtotime($setting["endtime"]);//Or whatever your local copy of the end time is
$current=time();

$counter = $current>=$end?$setting["limit"]:round($setting['limit'] * ($current-$start)/($end-$start));

DB::update('settings')
    ->set(array('counter' => $counter))
    ->where('id', '=', $setting['id'])
        ->execute();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. The counter needs to take height from the current counter ($setting['counter']), because like what i tested now: Current count: 3489
$counter now: 1165 per minute (cronjob execution) <- thats way too high, if the end time is set to 7PM and current time over here is only 12AM

Comment: Does the counter NEED to be based on the previous count? @Karem

Comment: Lunis , Yes otherwise it will add too high number to the counter, while theres still many cronjob executions left

Comment: If you looked at the code in my answer you'd see that it doesn't add to the counter, it SETS it. @Karem

Comment: lets say the script executes 15 times timestart 00:00 - timeend 00:15, limit is 100. Then it should do 6,8 (round to 7) each execution/refresh, then it will get to around 100 after 15 executions and that is correct

Comment: Yes, and that's what this will do, although it bases it on the current time between the start and and time. Try it out, and make sure it's set to SET the counter, and not add to it. It will work. @Karem